# Recognizing a Single Letter in an image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm very new to OpenCV and using it for a project that involves trying to recognize a set of targets on the ground, from pictures taken from a drone flying overhead. Here's an example image (downscaled obviously)

[image]

Using the canny edge detection algorithm and OpenCV's ability to recognize contours, I've been able to crop out the two targets (along with a long list of false positives)

These are the targets

[image]
[image]

Here's an example of a random false positive (doesn't contain a letter)

[image]

I'm wondering where I should start to look in order to determine if these targets I've recognized and cropped have a letter on them or not, and if so, what letter it is. I know OpenCV is more than powerful enough to acomplish this - but what different methods are at my disposal, and which are best suited for recognizing a single letter like this?

Thanks!